# How to write the file from MultipartHttpServletRequest in java

Tags: java, file, servlets, multipart

As my backend end team will send the zip file , how to receive the file and store into the project location in java(eclipse)

As im tried some code using MultipartHttpServletRequest and getting multipart length and zip folder also created but when unable to extract that showing invalid. then how to write into the file . Please help me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieveBillerByFile1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void retrieveBillerByFile1(@RequestPart MultipartHttpServletRequest  request) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("RESPONSEEEE**"+request);
        
            Iterator<String> itrator = request.getFileNames();
            System.out.println("File Name:" + request.getFileNames());
            MultipartFile multiFile = request.getFile(itrator.next());
            System.out.println("itrator.next()" + itrator.next());
          
            
             try {
                // just to show that we have actually received the file
                     System.out.println("File Length:" + multiFile.getBytes().length);
                  String name = multiFile.getOriginalFilename();
                System.out.println("name" + name);
                
                System.out.println("multiFile.getBytes()" + multiFile.getBytes());
                BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("D:\\cedge_uat\\" + name ));
                w.write(new String(multiFile.getBytes()));
                w.flush();

               
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Exception("Error while loading the file");
            }
        
    
}
```

Another Way I have tried but fileItem getting as null

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieveBillerByFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void retrieveBillerByFile(@RequestPart HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("RESPONSEEEE**"+request);
        System.out.println("request**"+request);
        
        
          // checks if the request actually contains upload file
        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            System.out.println("Form must has enctype=multipart/form-data.**");
            // if not, we stop here
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("Error: Form must has enctype=multipart/form-data.");
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }
 
        // configures upload settings
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        // sets memory threshold - beyond which files are stored in disk
        factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);
        // sets temporary location to store files
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
 
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
         
        // sets maximum size of upload file
        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
         
        // sets maximum size of request (include file + form data)
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
 
        // constructs the directory path to store upload file
        // this path is relative to application's directory
      //  String uploadPath = servletContext.getRealPath("")+ File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
         
        String uploadPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/xml") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        // creates the directory if it does not exist
        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdir();
        }
        System.out.println("uploadPath\n"+ uploadPath);
        try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            System.out.println("formItems**"+formItems);
            if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {
                // iterates over form's fields
                for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                    System.out.println("item**"+item);
                    // processes only fields that are not form fields
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        System.out.println("fileName**"+fileName);
                        String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                        File storeFile = new File(filePath);
 
                        // saves the file on disk
                        item.write(storeFile);
                        System.out.println("success");
                        request.setAttribute("message",
                            "Upload has been done successfully!");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception"+ ex.getMessage());
            request.setAttribute("message",
                    "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Anyone please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can add another param in the method --

```
@RequestParam MultipartFile file
```

so your method will be --

```
public @ResponseBody void retrieveBillerByFile1(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @RequestPart MultipartHttpServletRequest  request) throws Exception
```

And then manipulate the file using java file apis

Comment: Can you explain detail,  so how to use the request and file both. I didn't understand

Comment: Can you check my above code, i have tried another way first and second SOP is printing and

Comment: ,As per your comments ,i have added , and printed file.getoriginalfilename:
name**HGA1F0FA8C0000006379.zip

Comment: String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + name;
               System.out.println("filePath" + filePath);
               
                       File dest = new File(filePath);
                       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                        fos.write( file.getBytes() );
                        fos.close();